# ansible unable to connect to centos

Tags: ansible

When i try connecting to CentOS server, i get following error

```
boby@hon-pc-01:~/www/ansible $ ansible centos -vvv -i hosts -a "uname -a"
Using /home/boby/www/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
<root@209.236.74.192:3333> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<root@209.236.74.192:3333> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -q -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=root -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/boby/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -tt root@209.236.74.192:3333 'mkdir -p "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1484629049.5-55764328572466 )" && echo "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1484629049.5-55764328572466 )"'
root@209.236.74.192:3333 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "ERROR! SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. We recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which will enable SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue", 
    "unreachable": true
}
boby@hon-pc-01:~/www/ansible $
```

I am able to connect Debian server with out any issue

```
boby@hon-pc-01:~/www/ansible $ ansible ubuntu -vvv -i hosts -a "uname -a"
Using /home/boby/www/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
<vm705n> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<vm705n> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -q -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o Port=3333 -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=root -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/boby/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -tt vm705n 'mkdir -p "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1484629067.62-202068262196976 )" && echo "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1484629067.62-202068262196976 )"'
<vm705n> PUT /tmp/tmpWzw_nH TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1484629067.62-202068262196976/command
<vm705n> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o Port=3333 -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=root -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/boby/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r '[vm705n]'
<vm705n> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<vm705n> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -q -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o Port=3333 -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=root -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/boby/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -tt vm705n 'LANG=en_IN LC_ALL=en_IN LC_MESSAGES=en_IN /usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1484629067.62-202068262196976/command; rm -rf "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1484629067.62-202068262196976/" > /dev/null 2>&1'
vm705n | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
Linux hon-vpn 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2 (2016-04-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux

boby@hon-pc-01:~/www/ansible $
```

Here is my hosts file

```
boby@hon-pc-01:~/www/ansible $ cat hosts
[ubuntu]
vm705n:3333

[centos]
root@209.236.74.192:3333
boby@hon-pc-01:~/www/ansible $
```

Any idea why it is not working for CentOS 6 server ?

**EDIT**

I got it fixed. The problem was root@ in hosts file. For some reason, the SSH command did not take port 3333 because root@ present on host file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i am able to connect to ssh on Centos Server.     

    boby@hon-pc-01:~ $ ssh -p 3333 root@209.236.74.192
    Last login: Tue Jan 17 06:10:02 2017 from 59.98.136.13
    root@server2 [~]# logout
    Connection to 209.236.74.192 closed.
    boby@hon-pc-01:~ $

Comment: I got it fixed, the problem was  -o Port=3333 missing in the first ssh command generated by ansible. I removed root@ (user name part) from the hosts file and it started working properly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in hosts file.

```
boby@hon-pc-01:~/www/ansible $ cat hosts
[ubuntu]
vm705n:3333

[centos]
root@209.236.74.192:3333
boby@hon-pc-01:~/www/ansible $
```

Replaced root@209.236.74.192:3333 with 209.236.74.192:3333 and it started working.